# How to do propensity score matching in R on a dataset of 10 million patients (won't fit into RAM)?

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I need to do some propensity score matching. My dataset is way too large to fit into RAM, which I see as R's biggest problem right now.

I see that the ff and ffbase packages are what I need.
I connected to Postgres and that's no problem and I sucked in a 50 gb file.

But the matchit and match packages can't be called on an ffdf object.

Is there a way to use matchit or match methods (or any other 3rd party package) with ff package?  If not, I guess I'm in trouble.

Is chunking a possibility here? If so, I'd appreciate a code snippet since the documentation is esoteric to me.  Any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: First off matching algorithms are notorious for computational inefficiency, have you considered other semi-parametric techniques such as Inverse probability weighting and double-robust regression?

Comment: Thanks, but I am a newbie and not that sure what the differences are.  It seems the medical community wants to see propensity score matching.

Comment: With that many observations you can use direct covariate adjustment unless you have an incredible number of adjustment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Considered hiring an AWS R3 instance? They go up to 244 Gb RAM:

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Possibly less messing around than writing a chunking algorithm.